# find the maximal number of path graphs of size n fit in a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I am trying to find a way to calculate or approximate the number of path graphs that can fit in a grid graph. The path graph consists of different states of the nodes.

An example of this path graph is:
$1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3$
So state 1 wants to be connected to state 2 and so forth.

The goal is to find the optimal configuration of states on the nodes such that the path graph is satisfied the maximal times possible in a 10x10 grid graph with periodic boundaries.

In this example the path is satisfied 3 times.
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{matrix}

This is an example of a setting where this path graph is satisfied 8 times in a grid graph.
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 3 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 1
\end{matrix}

Is there a way to approximate the maximal number of satisfactions of a specific path graphs in a grid graph? I think it has something to do with partitions/number theory, but I can not find a specific solution to this problem. I hope someone can give me a direction to find a solution.

Comment: For an $n \times n$ grid, do you want only paths with $n$ nodes?  Does "periodic boundaries" mean node $(i,n)$ is adjacent to node $(i,1)$, and node $(n,j)$ is adjacent to node $(1,j)$?

Comment: For a 10x10 grid, I want to be able to calculate the paths with different size lengths (so length of the path = 2 / 3 / 4 / 5. The periodic boundaries as you understand them is how I mean it. 

The periodic boundaries are visualized in this figure:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Simulating-a-44-Ising-lattice-using-a-open-boundary-conditions-b-periodic-boundary_fig6_229438302

Comment: And do you want a separate grid for each path length or a single grid that counts all path lengths simultaneously?

Comment: A separate grid for each path length

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows. Let $P_n$ be the set of possible paths with $n$ nodes.  In particular, $|P_2|=400$, $|P_3|=1200$, $|P_4|=3600$, and $|P_5|=10000$. For path $p\in P_n$ and $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $(i_{p,k},j_{p,k})$ be the nodes in the path, in order.  For $(i,j)\in \{1,\dots,10\}^2$ and $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j,k}$ indicate whether node $(i,j)$ takes value $k$.  For $p\in P_n$, let binary decision variable $y_p$ indicate whether path $p$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_p y_p$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_k x_{i,j,k} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag1\\
y_p &\le x_{i_{p,k},j_{p,k},k} &&\text{for all $p,k,i_{p,k},j_{p,k}$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns exactly one value to each node.
Constraint $(2)$ forces the node values to be consistent with every selected path.

Here are the best solutions I have found for small $n$.  Not sure whether the last three are optimal.

$200$ paths (optimal) with $2$ nodes:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

$200$ paths with $3$ nodes:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3
```

$244$ paths with $4$ nodes:

```
1 2 3 4 3 4 3 2 1 4 
2 1 4 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 
3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 
4 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 
3 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 
4 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 
3 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
2 1 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 
1 2 3 2 1 2 3 4 1 2 
4 3 4 1 2 3 4 3 2 3
```

$316$ paths with $5$ nodes:

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 1 4 3 2 
2 1 2 5 4 3 2 5 4 3 
3 2 5 4 3 2 1 2 5 4 
4 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 4 
2 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 
4 5 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
3 4 5 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 
2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 1
```

Comment: wow this looks exactly how I mean it, can I ask how you generated these? or did you not automate it?

Comment: @Thomas I added an integer linear programming formulation to my answer.